# YouTube player error after updating on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

When I use the old YouTube player on my phone (before updating it), it works properly. But after I update my YouTube player, my android code Youtubeplayer shows this error. It just plays, stops, and shows this error. Any ideas on what's causing it to stop?

```
YouTube video playback stopped because the player's view is not visible.
The view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView
{36d050c2 I.E..... R.....ID 0,0-540,960} has visibility "INVISIBLE".
```

Comment: Any Logcat message? any error output? It is always nice to shown the info available, so that people may direct you where you need to check. So: Logcat + AndroidManifest.xml + Activity and Layout are good things to post in the question as well.

Comment: It may be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784730/unable-to-play-some-youtube-videos-using-youtube-android-player-api) question. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7586).

Comment: @not_a_bot... yes related to that