# Unable to play Youtube videos using YouTube Android Player API

Tags: android, youtube, integration

I am getting this error "Cannot load modern controls UI. Upgrade to the latest version of the Android YouTube API." I used `youtubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);`

but still getting same error also i go through [Unable to play some Youtube videos using YouTube Android Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784730/unable-to-play-some-youtube-videos-using-youtube-android-player-api)

But still getting error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this bug because i am using Fragment inside Youtube Fragment. i removed the inner fragment my problem is solved and now Youtube Videos are working properly.

Comment: What are you talking about? You've just saved my day! Thanks.